# Floating-point numbers in C

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

I'm using the following code to get the output up to 5 decimal characters of any number input by user when divided by 1, I have to typecast it with `(float)`.

Can any one tell me how this can be done without typecasting or using float constant?

```
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%.5 ", 1/(float)n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... how to get a float without a float? Why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: You can do implicit conversion to introduce float/double into the calculation by `1./n` or `1f/n`. Either of the operands of division operator must be float/double so that the result is float/double. For the `printf`, you must use `%.5f` (float) or `%.5lf` (double).

Comment: "output upto 5 decimal characters", you're not converting it to decimal, but to float.

Comment: This is a nice riddle :)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but its strange when I am doing this :- `printf("%.5f ",(n*n+n)./(2*(n*n+n+1)));`  its showing syntax error..

Comment: @avinashse You can only put `.` after literals. You can't put it after an expression like `(n*n+n)`.

Comment: you can try fixed-point numbers, which handle float numbers with only integers. try google it.

Comment: Why could you possibly care that you have to use a float literal or cast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [use this piece of code](http://ideone.com/QYXRT) that uses only integers:

```
 printf(n==1?"1.00000":"0.%05d ", 100000/n);
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking your question strictly literally, you could do:

```
int main() {
    float n;
    scanf("%f",&n);
    printf("%.5f", 1/n);
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, there is no float literal and no `(float)` cast.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, this should do it:

`printf("%.5f ", 1/pow(n,1));`